# Connect EntityFramework to Lotus Notes

Tags: entity-framework, odbc, lotus-notes

theoretically I should be able to connect EntityFramework to any Db I can access through ODBC drivers, is this correct? So if I use a library like the one mentioned at http://www.connectionstrings.com/lotus-notes it should be possible to connect EF to Lotus Notes? 
I know this is something one should avoid ;) It's a one time only migration.

Comment: If you are successful, would you come back and update your question, or add your own answer?  I'm really curious if this would work :)

Comment: Don't you need an EF provider to be able to connect to a store? What will translate your queries to the form that the database understands?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, but I would look here for the latest driver:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/notessql/